# How to access the subgraph added as node in networkx graph?

Tags: python, networkx

Let's say I have such a graph:

```py
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(12, 8), (12, 11), (11, 8), (11, 7), (8, 1), (8, 9), (8, 13), (7, 0), (7, 6), (0, 1), (0, 2), (6, 2), (6, 5), (5, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4), (1, 4), (4, 9), (4, 10), (10, 14), (10, 13), (14, 15), (13, 15), (13, 14)])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Then I'm going to take nodes `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` out of the main graph, move them to the subgraph, add this subgraph to the main graph and create missing edges:

```py
subgraph_nodes = set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
subgraph = G.subgraph(subgraph_nodes).copy()
G.add_node(subgraph)

for subgraph_node in subgraph_nodes:
    neighbors = set(G.neighbors(subgraph_node))
    external_neighbors = neighbors - subgraph_nodes
    for ext_neighbor in external_neighbors:
        G.add_edge(ext_neighbor, subgraph)
    G.remove_node(subgraph_node)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Now in `G`'s nodes I have the following:

```py
G.nodes()
```

`NodeView((12, 8, 11, 7, 9, 13, 6, 5, 10, 14, 15, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x7f34025a8fa0>))`

So the question is - how can I access the subgraph via `G.nodes()` interface (like `G.nodes()[12]` for the node `12`)?

Here is colab link for convenience - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j_7SNv6ixV0OVya3vWYmjOQZgwJH3m1v?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

You can select them as list item if you output your nodes as list. Here is an example to draw your subgraph:

```
#using -1 because in this case your subgraph is in last position:
nx.draw(list(G.nodes())[-1], with_labels=True)
```

more information and examples can be found on the NetworkX page:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html

Anyways if you want to search for a node with subgraph you can do this:

```
for node in G.nodes():
  try:
    print(node.subgraph)
  except:
    print("No Subgraph")
```

Comment: That means I need to know its position in the list, which is not always possible. Neither can I see how to determine it automatically

Comment: ofcourse for that you need to go deeper and either find your subgraph through some specific characteristics. but i dont know what that has to do with your initial question. If you want to go deeper into that topic i suggest you create a new stackoverflow question about it

Comment: Anyways look above.

Comment: My initial question is "how can I access the subgraph via `G.nodes()` interface (like `G.nodes()[12]`", not how to get the element from the list by index or how to iterate through the nodes

Comment: well u cant. you could only if you assign your subgraph to a further variable. one way to to that is through  my_subgraph = G.nodes()[12]